# Using variables in HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

In my use case, I need to something like this below

```
set x=<query1> // This query 1 returns a value 75
set y=x
print y // only for testing

select * from table1 where id=y

set var1=<query2>
set var2=<query3>
set var3=<query4>
set count = var1+var2+var3
```

Is it possible to do like this in Hive? I am struggling to even run a simple query and put the results in a variable. Any clue will be really helpful.

To start with, I am trying to do something like below

```
set param = SELECT P.K_ID FROM T_PARAMETER AS P, T_TOOL_PARAMETER AS M WHERE P.K_PARAMETER_GENERIC = 6 AND P.K_ID = M.K_PARAMETER AND M.k_airborn = 17;


INSERT INTO T_TEMP SELECT T.F_RECORDEDVALUE, T.F_VALIDITY FROM T_RECORD AS T WHERE T.K_PARAMETER=${hiveconf:param};
```

The above query fails. I am not sure whether the syntax is correct or not. The error I get is

```
cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'P' '.' in expression specification

If I put the double quotes in where clause WHERE T.K_PARAMETER="${hiveconf:parameter}";, then, No error comes but the T_TEMP is empty.
```

If I hardcode the value set parameter = 36 and use in where clause WHERE T.K_PARAMETER=${hiveconf:parameter};, then, it works cleanly.
The issue comes when only i try to put the results of a query into a variable

I prefer to use Hue as I need to write many queries like this.

Comment: you may have a look at this: http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/1462avsbxr/storing-result-of-a-query-in-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on terminal

```
var1=$(hive -e "select count(*) from table1;")
var2=$(hive -e "select count(*) from table2;")
var1=$(hive -e "select count(*) from table3;")
count=$(( $var1 + $var1 + $var3))
echo $count
```

on hive console

```
INSERT INTO T_TEMP SELECT T.F_RECORDEDVALUE, T.F_VALIDITY FROM T_RECORD AS T WHERE T.K_PARAMETER In (SELECT P.K_ID FROM T_PARAMETER AS P, T_TOOL_PARAMETER AS M WHERE P.K_PARAMETER_GENERIC = 6 AND P.K_ID = M.K_PARAMETER AND M.k_airborn = 17);
```

Comment: This is working with terminal. However, is there a way to do it in HQL script? I am using Hue to write my HQL script and the script will contains many such operations. It will be very time consuming if i were to do it via terminal.

Comment: Please look into my post once more as I have added more information

Comment: Actually we can use variable in query but can't stored the result in variable.(Not confident). What is the output of your query? I will give work around of your problem

Comment: An integer is the return value.

Comment: SELECT P.K_ID FROM T_PARAMETER AS P, T_TOOL_PARAMETER AS M WHERE P.K_PARAMETER_GENERIC = 6 AND P.K_ID = M.K_PARAMETER AND M.k_airborn = 17; you have not mention join condition. Query is not right

Comment: But this query runs and returns the result

Comment: if result is right, put it in subquery - INSERT INTO T_TEMP SELECT T.F_RECORDEDVALUE, T.F_VALIDITY FROM T_RECORD AS T WHERE T.K_PARAMETER=subquery

Comment: 'IN' helps .. Can you suggest some work around for create multiple variables, each stores results of a query, and then calculate a sum?

Comment: Not cleared your problem. Make a another question, sample input with sample output. I definetly give you the answer, if not possible I will give you the work around of that problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822766/creating-and-sum-the-values-of-variables-in-hiveql